# Flow marked as failed if Excel "Get Rows" returns 404 Not Found

Tags: power-automate

I am looking for some value in Excel spreadsheet but it's not obligatory thus in the middle of the flow I added parallel operation with two following parallel *Set Variable* steps: when the previous operation succeeds (*`var = excel_cell_value`*) and when it fails (*`var = default_value`*).

Unfortunately, when there is no such value in a `spreadsheet` the whole flow is marked as `FAILED` despite it ran successfully in fact.

How to solve that, guys? Thanks in advance